# PHP filesize won't update; even with clearstatcache();

Tags: javascript, php

I have this file:

```
<html>
</html>
<script>

    setInterval(function () {
            <?php clearstatcache(); ?>
            var ss = "<?php echo filesize('log.html'); ?>";
            console.log(ss);
    },100);

</script>
```

But if I empty out the file `log.html` the browser still outputs the old filesize. Am I doing something wrong here? If so how can I fix it?

Comment: _'Am I doing something wrong here?'_ - yes: you're trying to execute a PHP script (which __runs on the server__ before the page is emitted) from inside a Javascript script (which __runs on the client__ after the page is emitted. It doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript you are running keeps outputting the same data that has been sent when the page loaded. Thus it never change, as it is not reading from server.

You would need to use ajax to re-read data from server whenever needed to update.